# How to get static return type of a class method in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, return-type

I have the following interface A and classes B and C (with PHP8.0 static return type):

```
interface A {
    public function getSomething(): self;
}

class B implements A {
    public function getSomething(): self
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

class C implements A {
    public function getSomething(): static
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

How to get the return type of method `getSomething()` of a new instance? Is it possible with [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getreturntype.php) class?

```
$classes = [ 'B', 'C'];

$newClass = $classes[array_rand($classes)];

print((new ReflectionClass(new $newClass()))->getMethod('getSomething')->getReturnType());
```

My example returns `self` or `static` which is not my desired output. I want to get a concrete name class (`A`, `B` etc.) instead. Is it possible explicitly without any workaround?

Comment: The only way I know how to do it is via annotations.  Because your interface defines the method, the implementation will have to return the type A but you can still use `/** @return B */` on the implementing method.  Alternatively, I think you can omit the return type self on A::getSomething() and then further restrict it in B.

Comment: When you know its `self`, can't you just use `$newB->getName()`?

Comment: I modified question. I don't want to pre-define what type method can return. Is it possible in PHP for now?

Comment: When you know it's `self` or `static`, why not return the value of `$newClass`? It has the class name you want.

Answer (score 5):

Great solution is a part of the "[Nette framework](https://nette.org)" dev-stack, that provides [`Nette\Utils\Reflection`](https://api.nette.org/utils/master/Nette/Utils/Reflection.html) helper.

More info here: https://doc.nette.org/en/utils/reflection#toc-getreturntype

Answer (score 0):

After investigation it's not possible. `ReflectionClass` returns only defined return type, not real one when using types: static or self (`A`. `B`, etc.)